# Why arc4random_uniform can be set as a constant?

Tags: swift, random, constants, arc4random

Why arc4random_uniform can be set as a constant? I noticed that in multiple examples.
arc4random_uniform generates a new value every time it is called and I thought value of a constant should never change? It looks much more like a variable.

Comment: `arc4random_uniform` is a function that generates random numbers. Why would it stay constant?

Comment: What do you mean "set as a constant"? `arc4random_uniform` is imported from a library. It is not a variable that you define yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is confusing.

You can make a thing a constant. In this case, the thing is a function. You're setting up a constant reference to a function. Think of arc4random_uniform() as a random number factory. It is constant. It sits there, waiting to create random numbers, just like a car factory, sits their waiting to create cars.

When you call the random number factory, it gives you a new random number, but the thing itself, the random number factory, remains constant.

### Edit:

If you had a variable reference to a function instead, then you could store different random number factories in that variable. Each one might have different performance characteristics (speed, true randomness of the results, range of results, etc.)

Comment: Thank you Duncan, it is confusing, but you brought some light in!